# ngStorage breaking my application tests

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner

I have an Angular app with a simple karma test and a very simple configuration using requirejs and Angular 1.2.28. My test is ok.

```
/**
 * Created by jose on 7/12/2015.
 */
/*global module, inject */

define(['home', 'angularMocks','ngStorage'], function(app) {
    'use strict';
    describe('homeController', function () {
        var scope, $location, createController;
        beforeEach(module('homeApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$location_) {
            $location = _$location_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            createController = function () {
                return $controller('homeController', {
                    '$scope': scope
                });
            };
        }));

        it('should have message', function () {
            var controller = createController();
            $location.path('/');
            expect($location.path()).toBe('/');
            expect(scope.message).toEqual('This is Add new order screen');
        });
    });

});
```

My module:

```
/**
 * Created by jose on 7/12/2015.
 */
'use strict';

define(['angular', 'angularRoute'], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('homeApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                    controller: 'homeController'
                })
                .when('/404', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/404'
                });
        }
    ]);

    app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
    });

    return app;
});
```

Unfortunately, when I try to add ngStorage as a dependency for this module, it cannot works anymore. Even try to add ngStorage to my karma configuration raise an error like this:

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (app) {
```

It only happens when I try to use ngStorage, when I just comment it into my karma.conf file error disappears and everything works fine...
In case of not being possible using ngStorage with Karma there are another alternatives for ngStorage? thanks

karma.conf

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jul 13 2015 09:49:28 GMT-0300 (Hora est. Sudamérica Pacífico)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test-main.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
      {pattern: 'javascripts/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'javascripts/config.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Project is at github: https://github.com/jbarros35/node/tree/master/angulartemplate

kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are not the only one receiving errors trying to use Karma and ngStorage together. The guys at Karma have made some of their code available to help resolve the issue. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of `ngStorage` you'll see that it calls `define`. So it is a proper AMD modules. Each AMD module you use in a Karma setup must be loaded with `included: False` in `files`:

```
{ pattern: 'bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js', included: False }
```

Otherwise, Karma will load it with a `script` element, and you will get the error you got.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the async load feature of require js. Errors can be solved by this way

Go to the test-main.js.
add shim there in this way

```
shim:{
   'yourJsModule':{
      deps:['angular','yourApp']
   }
}
```

replace "yourJsModule" with the your angular file you intend to test and the 'yourApp' with your angular module file...

Comment: The OP's own modules are proper AMD modules: they use `define`. When a module uses `define` you **must not** set a `shim` for it. Therefore it is erroneous to tell the OP to use `define` with the OP's modules.

Comment: If you don't use shim then how you are going to give the dependencies?

Comment: The dependencies are given to the `define` call.

Comment: @Louis I've tried that too but then also it was throwing errors. However after adding  the deps in the shim all the errors gone.